# Resolving this recurrence equation

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion

I have this recurrence equation:

$T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + \mathcal{O}(n)$

$T(1) = 1$

I know that the result is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ but i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you looked up? What are you confused about?

Comment: Hi jason, i would like to know which are the steps to follow to solve that recurrence equation (and recurrence equation in general). Thanks for help, Federico

Comment: The easiest way is to use [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: If you want to see how to come up with recursion equations, you can see the [base question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers), and read through the answers, to get result for general approach.

Comment: Try the reference question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a basic one. Since you did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own, we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a [recursion tree](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html). The sum of the costs per level is less then $c\cdot n$, for $c$ being the constant in the $O(n)$. The tree has roughly $n\log_4 n$ full levels, and the deepest level is $n \log_{4/3} n$. So, summing up over all levels gives $T(n)=O(n\log n)$.